# Showing $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ with the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

So I want to say we let $f:S^1→\mathbb R^2$ be a homeomorphism, and since we can find a bijection, I want to say we can open an open set in the plane using the standard product topology, and take its pre-image, which is assumed to be open by continuity of f but this is not always the case in $S^1$.

Help or hint please.

Comment: Do you know compactness?

Comment: very well, oh I see where you're going, use that the circle is and R2 isn't? I Wass trying to avoid that proof, its sort of the easier way out no?

Comment: @Randall and compactness is a topological property it is preserved under continuous functions

Comment: Why avoid it?  It’s the shortest possible proof.

Comment: If you don't want to use compactness, you could use connectedness. Removing any two points from the circle disconnects it, but this isn't true about the plane.

Comment: @SantanaAfton I know I could use any topological property lol, I want to know if there is another way or not a more direct way using a very arbitrary element of the product topology in R2 and show f inverse of this cannot be open in the unit circle. Im starting to think the only proofs are using topological properties/invariants. cause images of compact and connected are respectively compact and connected under continuous functions.

Comment: @Randall I was wondering if there is a more direct proof without the use of topological properties. thanks so much though!!

Comment: Homeomorphism is a topological thing, so any property you use will necessarily be topological.   It looks like what you might be thinking of is something similar to "Invariance of domain" though, by which the embedding of $S^1$ would have to be open (but isn't).  Note though that this is harder than using compactness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least two proofs come to mind.

1. $S^1$ is compact, and $\mathbb R^2$ is not, but any continuous map takes compact sets to compact sets, so $\mathbb R^2$ cannot be the image under any continuous map of $S^1$ with the given topologies.
2. $S^1$ minus any two points is disconnected, but $\mathbb R^2$ minus any two points remains connected. This forms a proof as follows : consider $p,q \in \mathbb R^2$  ,then the set $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{p,q\}$ is a connected (open) set, hence its image under any injective continuous map $f$ to $\mathbb S^1$ should be connected, but the image is $\mathbb S^1 \setminus \{f(p),f(q)\}$ which is disconnected, since $f(p) \neq f(q)$ by injectivity of $f$. Therefore, no injective continuous map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $S^1$ exists in the given topologies.

Also see if something like this works out (exercise) : $S^1$ is the quotient space of $[0,1]$ under the identification $a \sim b \iff a=b $ or $\{a,b\} = \{0,1\}$. Therefore, any continuous map $f$ from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R^2$ lifts to a continuous map $\psi$ from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^2$, which satisfies $\psi(0) = \psi(1)$, via $\psi(a) = f([a])$.  The reverse is also true : any such continuous map $\phi : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ with $\phi(0) = \phi(1)$ factors to a continuous map given by $g([a]) = \phi(a)$. So, we have an identification between continuous maps from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R^2$, and from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^2$.

Using the fact that $[0,1]$ is a bounded interval, see if you can make any argument using the above identification  to show that $S^1  \not \cong \mathbb R^2$. This is a more comfortable setting to try out your "direct method" that you were attempting in the post.

Comment: that is exactly what I needed, my first thoughts were to use connectedness and compactness but was trying to do it without the use of these topological invariants. thanks for that proof, it looks like it works to me and I have to wrap my head round it some more. I was more or less tying to do this using basic principles of topology rather than compactness/connectedness tricks.

Comment: It is ok. Usually, you will need to be familiar with these tricks : more than the basic principles, they will come to your help as you progress.

Comment: exactly, I wanted to know all the different proofs for this one, I like the proof how it uses covering spaces which I was rusty with. Thanks so much! im working through it now